# Unlocking more then one column with .Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add

Tags: vba, excel

Hey i have a smal problem that i cant seam to solve... so i could really use some help!
Im trying to unlock 4 columns in my code, but i can only unlock 3... if i add my fourth column i get error "Method 'Range' of object'_global' failed"

```
Sub UnLockStatusSheet()
    StatusSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select

    ' Allow Software column header
    Dim SoftwareRange As Range
    Set SoftwareRange = FindAllColumnHeaderIndex(2, "Planned to be implemented")
    For Each Cell In SoftwareRange
        StatusSheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="Software" & Cell.Column, _
                Range:=Range(Cell.Offset(-1, 0).Address)
    Next Cell

    ' Protect sheet except applicable rows
    Dim AllowedRange As Range
    Set AllowedRange = StatusSheet.Range("E2", "E" & LastRowInOneColumn(1))

    For Each Line In AllowedRange.Rows
        If (Line.Value = "Applicable") Then
            StatusSheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="AllowedRange" & Line.Row, _
                Range:=Range("M" & Line.Row & ":AX" & Line.Row)
            StatusSheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="AllowedRangeUser" & Line.Row, _
                Range:=Range("D" & Line.Row) '<<<<< my problem is here!!! 

        End If
    Next Line

    ' Enable autofiltering
    StatusSheet.Rows("2:2").AutoFilter

    ' Lock sheet
    StatusSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True _
        , AllowFormattingCells:=True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

i want to add `& "E" & Line.Row` after `"D" & Line.Row`so i unlock both column D and E and not just D. But i can´t i just gets error... Without the `& "E" & Line.Row` the code works fine and i don´t understand why... Is there an explanation to this problem? Thanks

Comment: do you add '& "E" & Line.Row' or '& ":E" & Line.Row'?

Comment: '& "E" & Line.Row' just for that column

Comment: the ':' before the 'E' is important like in the code line before. See ':AX'  -- 'Range:=Range("M" & Line.Row & ":AX" & Line.Row)'

Comment: Oh man im dumb, haha! Thank you! why did i not try that...

Comment: fwiw it could be either a colon or a comma.